# Getting error while download file in Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am facing a problem in my application. 
I have some section in application from where user can download data in excel file.Code is working absolutely fine in local, Means file is getting download properly in local with every browser. But when we download file from test or live server its shows a popup with following error

> "C:\Users\PHT~1.AMI\AppData\Local\Temp\hXybMbIw.xlsx.part
>   could not be saved, because the source
>   file could not be read. Try again
>   later, or contact the server
>   administrator."

in case of firefox browser only.

I am using following code for file download

```
   function ExportToExcel(isJdl) {
        var url = '/Product/ExportToExcel?isJdl=' + isJdl
                + "&projID=" + _projID
                + "&PlanPages=" + escape($("#PlanPages").val())
                + "&SpecSections=" + escape($("#SpecSections").val())
                + "&Addenda=" + escape($("#Addenda").val())
                + "&HighLite=" + $("#chkHighLite").attr("checked");
        Download(url);
    }

    function Download(url) {
        var win = window.open(url, "DownloadWin", "resizable=0,status=0,toolbar=0,width=600px,height=300px");
        win.focus();
        win.moveTo(100, 100);
    }
```

Controller Code is as follow:-

```
public void ExportToExcel(bool isJdl, string projID, string planPages, string specSections, string addenda, string HighLite)
        {
            int pID = int.Parse(projID.Decrypt());
            bool HightLiteVal = false;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HighLite))
                HightLiteVal = Convert.ToBoolean(HighLite);

            Highmark.BLL.Models.Project proj = Highmark.BLL.Services.ProjectService.GetByID(pID);


            if (proj != null)
            {
                proj.PlanPages = planPages;
                proj.SpecSections = specSections;
                proj.Addenda = addenda;
                proj.HighLite = HightLiteVal;
                using (OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
                {

                    OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage pck1 = Highmark.BLL.Services.ProjectService.GetExcelFile(isJdl, pck, pID, proj, planPages, specSections, addenda);

                    string name = string.Format("{0}", proj.ProjectName);
                    if (pck1.Workbook.Worksheets.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //Write it back to the client
                        Response.ContentType = "Application/vnd.ms-Excel";

                        //Remove Invalid Character from File Name
                        name = name.RemoveInvalidCharFromFileName();

                        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;   filename=\"" + name + "_HighEST.xlsx\"");
                        Response.BinaryWrite(pck1.GetAsByteArray());
                    }
                }

            }
            else
                Response.Write("Error: Invalid request, please try again");
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have some FF download manager extension?

Anyway, this problem usually happens when your security software stops the download and then resumes it.

if the file is being downloaded to you temp folder, FF might have problems accessing this folder and resume the download.

Another solution might be to close FF and delete this file: "compreg.dat" from the profile folder.

source:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Source_file_could_not_be_read

Comment: thanks for reply elad, i have check this article also. i have find the path for profile as  "C:\Users\pht.amits\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles". But there is two folder under profile folder named as '7w8z2coa.default' and 'v674fnkk.default'. Where can i find "compreg.dat" file?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same eror in following code.By it is resolved by commenting Response.Flush(),Response.Close(),Response.End() in my case.

```
public void ExportClentList(string[] DataArray, string ToatalHours)
    {
        using (OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
            {
                OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage excelExportedData = GetBackToClientProjectReport(pck, DataArray, ToatalHours);

                if (excelExportedData.Workbook.Worksheets.Count > 0)
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "Application/vnd.ms-Excel";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;   filename=\"BackToClientProjectReport.xlsx\"");
                    Response.BinaryWrite(excelExportedData.GetAsByteArray());
                    //Response.Flush();
                    //Response.Close();
                    //Response.End();
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "Application/vnd.ms-Excel";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;   filename=\"BackToClientProjectReport.xlsx\"");
                    OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage pc1k1 = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage();
                    ExcelWorksheet ws = pc1k1.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
                    ExcelRange r = ws.Cells[1, 1];
                    r.Value = "No Record Found";
                    Response.BinaryWrite(pc1k1.GetAsByteArray());
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Good man! This worked for me too. I only had Flush() and removed it and it worked. It seems you dont really need to do anything after the BinaryWrite() because it will affect the stream before the download has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

Never hardcode urls. Always use url helpers when dealing with urls:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Product")?isJdl=' + isJdl
            + "&projID=" + _projID
            + "&PlanPages=" + escape($("#PlanPages").val())
            + "&SpecSections=" + escape($("#SpecSections").val())
            + "&Addenda=" + escape($("#Addenda").val())
            + "&HighLite=" + $("#chkHighLite").attr("checked");
```

When your application is deployed on the live server there is the name of the application that need to be appended. So the correct url would be:

```
/AppName/Product/ExportToExcel?...
```

instead of:

```
/Product/ExportToExcel?...
```

That's the reason why you should always use url helpers when working with urls.

Comment: Ok, Is that the reason for error? I am checking the same with my code.

Comment: @Amit, this could be one of the reasons. There might be other problems as well with your code. Unfortunately you haven't shown your controller action so it would be impossible for me to help you further.

Comment: I have added the controller above.Please have a look and let me know.Thanks